# What is the point of error checking in this code?

Tags: c, opencl

I was looking at the example code for clfft.  I notice that they keep assigning a value to err after each function call.

```
err = clfftCreateDefaultPlan(&planHandle, ctx, dim, clLengths);

/* Set plan parameters. */
err = clfftSetPlanPrecision(planHandle, CLFFT_SINGLE);
err = clfftSetLayout(planHandle, CLFFT_COMPLEX_INTERLEAVED, CLFFT_COMPLEX_INTERLEAVED);
err = clfftSetResultLocation(planHandle, CLFFT_INPLACE);

/* Bake the plan. */
err = clfftBakePlan(planHandle, 1, &queue, NULL, NULL);

/* Execute the plan. */
err = clfftEnqueueTransform(planHandle, CLFFT_FORWARD, 1, &queue, 0, NULL, NULL, &bufX, NULL, NULL);

/* Wait for calculations to be finished. */
err = clFinish(queue);

/* Fetch results of calculations. */
err = clEnqueueReadBuffer( queue, bufX, CL_TRUE, 0, N * 2 * sizeof( *X ), X, 0, NULL, NULL );
```

I understand the need for error checking but they never actually check the return value.  They just assign it to err and overwrite it.  In my code I have this...

```
status = clfftSetPlanPrecision(bpm->fft_plan, bpm->float_type);
    if(status != CLBPM_SUCCESS)
        goto cleanup;

    status = clfftSetLayout(bpm->fft_plan, CLFFT_COMPLEX_INTERLEAVED, CLFFT_COMPLEX_INTERLEAVED);
    if(status != CLBPM_SUCCESS)
        goto cleanup;

    status = clfftSetPlanScale(bpm->fft_plan, CLFFT_FORWARD, 1.0f / (bpm->grid_size * bpm->grid_size));
    if(status != CLBPM_SUCCESS)
        goto cleanup;

    status = clfftSetPlanScale(bpm->fft_plan, CLFFT_BACKWARD, 1.0f);
    if(status != CLBPM_SUCCESS)
        goto cleanup;

    status = clfftSetResultLocation(bpm->fft_plan, CLFFT_OUTOFPLACE);
    if(status != CLBPM_SUCCESS)
        goto cleanup;
```

Is the example code just bad code or is the error propagating through the function calls?

Comment: Post deceleration of `err`.  It is special somehow?

Comment: Here is the link to the full code (scroll down) https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clFFT  err is just of type cl_int

Comment: Not full code.  The definition of `type cl_int` is not there (AFAICT), maybe in `CL/cl.h`.  OTOH, I do not expect this line of inquiry to help anyway now.

Comment: It is badly written, you can tell by the totally wasted `clFinish()` followed by a blocking call. In addition to the not checked error return codes

Comment: That could be helpful during debugging - as you step through the code, you can watch `err`. But in general, yes, just poorly written code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be: a lazy programmer (aka "bad code").

You're right, it just throws each error value away, and doesn't check it.

This isn't very uncommon, since probably it works "most of the time" and the error paths rarely get used.

Comment: You would just not expect them to do something like this on the main example on the home page of their site.

Comment: @chasep255 True, but often that kind of "page one" example code is simplified to make the point clearer. Usually that's pointed out though, which doesn't seem to happen here.

Comment: I used to use |= for a series of errors, which seems to be a variation of this.

Comment: @joshpbarron, you can only do that if he errors a) do not culminate (I mean, can't continue after an error) and then b) errors are bit fields. Otherwise it is just as bad.

Comment: The only theory I have is that maybe subsequent function calls return the last error if there was one.  Probably just bad code.

Answer (score 5):

For me it looks like improvable code. It is better than just ignoring the return value, the usual way, because you can see the actual return value while debugging. In your example, where no special error handling is needed, for a better readability a macro could be an option:

```
#define ON_ERROR_GOTO_CLEANUP(status) if(status != CLBPM_SUCCESS) goto cleanup

ON_ERROR_GOTO_CLEANUP(clfftSetPlanScale(bpm->fft_plan, CLFFT_BACKWARD, 1.0f));
```

Comment: The debugging point is actually a very important one.  With optimization all off, the 'err' var would probably exist and get loaded from EAX, (or whatever), even if unused.  On a release build with all opti. on, it would all likely get removed.